# Given solution using Bitmask, I am unable to understand the evaluation of condition as marked in code

Tags: c++, bit, bitmask

I an unable to understand the bit masking used here, the given code is a solution of finding no of palindrome paths in a binary tree which contains digits 0-9 inclusive. I have marked the line in code with in a if statement.

This is the question of LeetCode contest. Question is as given:

Pseudo-Palindromic Paths in a Binary Tree,
Given a binary tree where node values are digits from 1 to 9. A path in the binary tree is said to be pseudo-palindromic if at least one permutation of the node values in the path is a palindrome.

Return the number of pseudo-palindromic paths going from the root node to leaf nodes.

```
    int pseudoPalindromicPaths (TreeNode* root) {
        return dfs(root, 0);
    }

    int dfs(TreeNode* root, int count) {
        if (!root) return 0;
        count ^= 1 << (root->val - 1);
        int res = dfs(root->left, count) + dfs(root->right, count);
        if (root->left == root->right && (count & (count - 1)) == 0) res++;
        //--------------------------------------^--THIS SECTION-----
        count ^= 1 << (root->val - 1);
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Where did you get this code snippet from? Does that place have any explanation of the algorithm and what it does? And please take it as a lesson to always include detailed comments in your own code explaining such "clever" tricks, what it does and why you choose to use it instead of something else. Such comments will not only help others who might read your code, but also help yourself if you need to maintain it in a couple of years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count & (count - 1) == 0
```

If count is a power of 2, this statement is true.

Example: Count = 8

```
00001000 = 8
&
00000111 = (8-1) = 7 
------------
00000000 = 0
```

Comment: Do you mean if we & an integer say **n** with **n-1** then it always gives **0**?

Comment: @Ujjwal.Maurya0619 no, only if it's a power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    public int traverse(TreeNode root, int numNode, int[] arr){
        arr[(root.val-1)]+=1;
        
        int path = 0;
        if(root.left!=null)
            path+=traverse(root.left, numNode+1, arr);
        
        if(root.right!=null)
            path+=traverse(root.right, numNode+1, arr);
        
        if((root.left==null)&&(root.right==null)){
            if((numNode%2)==0){
                boolean flag = true;
                for(int i: arr){
                    if((i%2)==1){
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(flag)
                    path+=1;
            }
            else{
                int numOdd = 0;
                for(int i: arr)
                    if((i%2)==1)
                        numOdd++;
                if(numOdd==1)
                    path+=1;
            }
        }
        
        arr[root.val-1]-=1;
        return path;
    }
    public int pseudoPalindromicPaths (TreeNode root) {
        return traverse(root, 1, new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0});
    }
}
```